# Visualizing the Schrödinger equation for dipole based interaction Hamiltonian

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, visualization, numerical-value

I want to evaluate and plot the solutions of coupled linear differential equations. For each time frame, I want to display the probability values (corresponding to mod square of these solutions), and have *k* such frames, going down. Equation is something like this:

```
sln = 
  DSolve[
    {I c1'[t] == c2[t] + .125 c3[t], 
     I c2'[t] == c1[t] + c3[t], 
     I c3'[t] == .125 c1[t] + c2[t], 
     c1[0] == 1, c2[0] == 0, c3[0] == 0}, 
    {c1[t], c2[t], c3[t]}, t]
```

When I evaluate the function, it doesn't give me numerical values, as a result I cannot plot the resultant solutions.

```
Array[Evaluate[{Abs[c1[t]]^2, Abs[c2[t]]^2, Abs[c3[t]]^2}], {t, 0, 20}] /. sln
```

`ArrayPlot` doesn't work because the Array doesn't give definite numerical values.

Since,

$\displaystyle{ \sum_{i=1}^{3} |c_i[t]|^2 = 1}$

at all times, a color gradient can be used to represent these values. `DensityPlot` doesn't help here because it requires two parameters.

Comment: Is this what you are after? `ArrayPlot @
 Table[{Abs[c1[t]]^2, Abs[c2[t]]^2, Abs[c3[t]]^2} /. sln[[1]], {t, 0, 
   20}]`

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I can add the RGBColor gradient now.

Comment: @ferro11001 Can you share the source of these equations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, the answer to your question is a straight forward one.

You wanted to plot the solutions of your system, which can be done like this,

```
{c1sol, c2sol, c3sol} = DSolveValue[{I c1'[t] == c2[t] + .125 c3[t], 
    I c2'[t] == c1[t] + c3[t], I c3'[t] == .125 c1[t] + c2[t], 
    c1[0] == 1, c2[0] == 0, c3[0] == 0}, {c1[t], c2[t], c3[t]}, t];

Plot[Evaluate[{Abs[c1sol]^2, Abs[c2sol]^2, Abs[c3sol]^2}], {t, 0, 20},
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

Now to extract data from the solution,

```
Abs[c1sol] /. t -> 0
```

> 1

If you want a data table of the solutions, then

```
TableForm[Table[{t, Abs[c1sol]^2, Abs[c2sol]^2, Abs[c3sol]^2}, {t, 0, 20}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, Prepend[{"c1", "c2", "c3"}, t]}]
```

[image]

```
ArrayPlot[Table[{Abs[c1sol]^2, Abs[c2sol]^2, Abs[c3sol]^2}, {t, 0, 20}], 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

[image]

Adopting @Sumit idea,

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{t, Abs[#]^2}, {t, 0, 20}], Filling -> Axis, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, RGBColor[1 - y, 0, y]], Frame -> True, Mesh -> Full, 
   MeshStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {c1sol, c2sol, c3sol}
```

[image]

```
{c1sol, c2sol, c3sol} = DSolveValue[{I c1'[t] == c2[t] + .125 c3[t], 
    I c2'[t] == c1[t] + c3[t], I c3'[t] == .125 c1[t] + c2[t], 
    c1[0] == c10, c2[0] == c10, c3[0] == c10}, {c1[t], c2[t], c3[t]}, 
   t];
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[{Abs[c1sol]^2, Abs[c2sol]^2, 
     Abs[c3sol]^2} /. {c10 -> m}, {m, 0.0, 2, 0.2}]], {t, 0, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I got the first graph. I was stuck at writing the simple (now) Table command and getting an ArrayPlot. Physically, this is the Schrödinger equation for dipole based interaction Hamiltonian. Thanks for improving the question as well.

Comment: @NisargBhatt My pleasure. If there is anything else then ask freely?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this !

```
nmax = 20
psi[n_, t_] = Sin[n t 2 Pi/nmax]^2;
Table[
 ListLinePlot[Table[{n, psi[n, t]}, {n, 0, nmax}], Filling -> Axis, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, RGBColor[1 - y, 0, y]],
 Frame -> True, Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]},
 ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> t]
, {t, 3}]
```

[image]

Or in a compact way

```
data = Flatten[Table[{n, t, psi[n, t]}, {n, 0, nmax}, {t, 1, 3, 0.1}],1];
ListPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[1 - z, 0, z]], 
 AxesLabel -> {"n", "t", "psi"}]
```

[image]